# Open a custom form from New item list button

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions

I'm looking to open a custom New Item form developed in SPFX on click on New Item button in SharePoint List, and on the edit form as well, I want my custom form to be load.

How can I implement such scenario? I'm using SharePoint Online modern view for this implementation with SharePoint framework 1.14.0 and PNP v2

Any help on this would be appreciated.

[image: Attaches is the picture for ref]

Answer (score 0):

Form customizer were released as part of the SharePoint Framework 1.15 using which you can customize SharePoint default list forms.

Check below Microsoft official documentations and videos for more information:

1. [SharePoint Framework v1.15 release notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.15)
2. [Build your first Form Customizer extension (preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer)
3. [Getting started on building custom list form components with SPFx v1.15.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LF5eQHBx10o)