# SharePoint list with a choice field; a new section with columns need to appear when a specific choice value is selected!

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, choice-field

I have a SharePoint list with a choice field column; when a specific choice value is selected, a new section with new columns need to appear. Is this possible?

Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SharePoint online modern experience, you can use conditional formulas to show or hide columns in a list or library form based on other column values.

**Example**:

```
=if([$Category] == 'Product Management', 'true', 'false')
```

Where `[$Category]` is in format `[$InternalNameOfColumn]`, which means you have to use the "internal name" of choice column in formula. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Note**: You have to add conditional formulas on individual columns in list form as you cannot write conditional formulas on sections in "body" layout.

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)

---

**Update from comments**:

For advanced list form customizations, you have below two options:

1. [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)
2. Use SPFx Form Customizer extension: check my answer given here for more information & links: [SPFx Form Customizer extension](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303837/open-a-custom-form-from-new-item-list-button/303838#303838)

Comment: Thank you. I'm realizing my question may not have made sense. I was hoping that the column wouldn't be hidden. I'm hoping that if a value (in this case, Hot Topics) is selected from the Request Type, it would open a new section of columns to fill out. Is that doable?

Comment: This is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities, you have to customize the list forms using power apps for advanced customizations.

Comment: Check updated answer for other available options for advance customizations in modern experience.

Answer (score 0):

Here're steps:

1.Click "+New" button -> Edit columns -> Choose the column you want to show -> Edit conditional formula.

[image]

[image]

2.Use this formula: =if([$choice] == 'test1', 'true', 'false')

Note: The column is represented by specifying the internal name of the field.

[image]

Comment: Detailed steps are already given in Microsoft official documentation link provided in my answer.