# How to use a SPFx Webpart as Custom Listform on SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, spfx, modern-experience, list-form

My web part is ready to use, it is a simple form with some logic.

I want to change in List "A" the default form of SharePoint. So, when I push "+ New", SharePoint shows me my web part, and not the default form. The editing any item is the same Story.

Anyone some idea? Is it possible without complex coding?

Comment: I think you need to build SPFx Form Customizer extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer

Comment: A webpart for read and write items, and an extendion for edit or write items?

Comment: You can use SharePoint default list and list view to show items and SPFx form customizer to add/edit items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to add SPFx *web part* on new/edit form of SharePoint list. However, you can reuse your form (UI/logic) in web part and create a SPFx form customizer for SharePoint list - this is officially supported by Microsoft.

SharePoint Framework (SPFx) Form customizer were released as part of the SharePoint Framework 1.15 using which you can customize SharePoint default list forms.

Check below Microsoft official documentations and videos for more information:

1. [SharePoint Framework v1.15 release notes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.15)
2. [Build your first Form Customizer extension (preview)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer)
3. [Getting started on building custom list form components with SPFx v1.15.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LF5eQHBx10o)

**Similar thread**: [Open a custom form from New item list button](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303837/open-a-custom-form-from-new-item-list-button/303838#303838)